# Creating cursor conditionally?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, cursor

I want to restrict the cursor result set based on  Employee ID  array passed to the function, otherwise if array iks null I want all the records.

**Here is the stuff i tried**

First created the array type

```
    create or replace type p_emp_arr as table of number
```

Function is

```
    create or replace
    FUNCTION getEmployee_func ( empID IN Number, empId_arr IN p_emp_arr)
    RETURN number IS
       total number(2) := 0;

      BEGIN 

      IF(empId_arr is null)
       THEN
        CURSOR empCursor IS
          SELECT * FROM Employee ;
       ELSE
        CURSOR empCursor IS
          SELECT * FROM Employee where empId in (p_emp_arr);
      END IF;

        ....
        RETURN total;
     END;
```

But getting  below error

```
   Error(12,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "empCursor" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;
```

Comment: You should declare `Explicit Cursor` in the declaration section of the PLSQL Block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REFCURSOR`;

Syntax would be like,

```
OPEN EMP_CURSOR FOR
  'SELECT * FROM Employee
       where empId in SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(:empId_arr)'
   USING empId_arr ;
```

Full block including the `FETCH`:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION getEmployee_func ( empID IN Number, empId_arr IN p_emp_arr)
RETURN number IS
  total number(2) := 0;
  MYREC Employee%ROWTYPE;

  EMP_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN 

  IF(empId_arr is null)
   THEN
    OPEN EMP_CURSOR FOR
      'SELECT * FROM Employee' ;
   ELSE
    OPEN EMP_CURSOR FOR
      'SELECT * FROM Employee
          where empId in SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(:empId_arr)'
      USING empId_arr ;
  END IF;

  LOOP
     FETCH EMP_CURSOR INTO MYREC;
     EXIT WHEN EMP_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
     .....
  END;
    ....
  RETURN total;
 END;
```